# Error to generate AmazonS3 file url with Symfony2, LiipImagineBundle and Gaufrette on Twig

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, liipimaginebundle, gaufrette

I'm using the LiipImagineBundle on Symfony2 and trying to integrate
with the gaufrette to catch images on amazonS3, but my "src" on images are wrong.
I don't know if the error is my configs so...

This twig code:

```
{{ '123.jpg' | imagine_filter('128_128_75_s3') }}
// return http://localhost/project/web/media/cache/resolve/128_128_75_s3/123.jpg  
// expected is http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/media/cache/resolve/128_128_75_s3/123.jpg
```

My sevices.yml:

```
services:
    amazonS3:
        class: AmazonS3
        arguments:
            options:
                key: %aws_key%
                secret: %aws_secret%

    liip_imagine.cache.resolver.amazon_s3:
        class: Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\Resolver\AmazonS3Resolver
        arguments:
            - "@amazonS3"
            - "%aws_bucket%"
        tags:
            - { name: 'liip_imagine.cache.resolver', resolver: 'resolver.amazon' }

    liip_imagine.binary.loader.stream.import:
        class: Liip\ImagineBundle\Binary\Loader\StreamLoader
        arguments:
            - 'gaufrette://import/'
        tags:
            - { name: 'liip_imagine.binary.loader', loader: 'import' }
```

My config.yml:

```
# Gaufrette media bundle
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        import:
            amazon_s3:
                amazon_s3_id: amazonS3
                bucket_name:  %aws_bucket%
                options:
                    create: true
    filesystems:
        import:
            adapter: import
            alias:   import
    stream_wrapper: ~

#Liip Imagine Bundle
liip_imagine:
    cache: resolver.amazon
    data_loader: stream.import
    filter_sets:
        128_128_75_s3:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [128, 128], mode: outbound }
```

Comment: Take a look a [this github issue](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/issues/496). Hope this help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AmazonS3Resolver is deprecated, try to use AwsS3Resolver:

```
#service.yml
awsS3:
    class: Aws\S3\S3Client
    factory_class: Aws\S3\S3Client
    factory_method:  factory
    arguments:
        -
            key:    %aws_key%
            secret: %aws_secret%
            region: %aws_region%

liip_imagine.cache.resolver.amazon_s3:
    class: Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\Resolver\AwsS3Resolver
    arguments:
        - "@awsS3"
        - %aws_bucket%
    tags:
        - {name: 'liip_imagine.cache.resolver', resolver: 'resolver_as3'}

#config.yml
liip_imagine:
    cache: resolver_as3
    data_loader: import
    filter_sets:
        128_128_75_s3:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [128, 128], mode: outbound }
```